# CakePHP database session handler and reactive programming

Tags: php, session, cakephp, reactive-programming, reactphp

Look at the following code:

```
public function step1 (){
    $this->Session->write('test.test', 1);
    sleep(10);

}

public function step2 () {
    if($this->Session->read('test.test')){
        $this->response->body('Great');
    }else{
        $this->response->body('Fail');
    }
}

public function remove () {
    $this->Session->delete('test.test');
}
```

If you execute step1 action, sleep 5 seconds, and execute step2 the result is 'Fail'. That means is not persisting session variable in the moment I call write method.

If you take a look to CakePHP DatabaseSession class, you can find this:

```
public function write($id, $data) {
    if (!$id) {
        return false;
    }
    $expires = time() + $this->_timeout;
    $record = compact('id', 'data', 'expires');
    $record[$this->_model->primaryKey] = $id;
    return $this->_model->save($record);
}
```

That's only an example of the problem. I'm using ReactPHP with CakePHP and EventSource in the browser. When you send a request, PHP releases the socket several times sending information to browser before script was finished. If the user click to second step and the first step has not finished yet, step2 throws an error because it's not able to read the session variable.

I think PHP only persists sessions when session_write_close is executed.

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');// CakeSession.php
```

How can I solve this?

Is it possible to save session before script finishes?

Comment: There are known problems with concurrent calls to CakePHP apps that use database sessions. Not sure if this will fix the issue, but are you using the latest 2.8 branch version? [`DatabaseSession::write()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Session/DatabaseSession.php#L116) is different from the code you provide.

Comment: I'm using 2.6, but I think the problem is in php, there is only one function to write session, session_write_close. session_write function doesn't exist. As a result, php only write session in File/Service/Database at the end of script.

Comment: @InigoFlores I was looking CakeSession v2.8 over and I think that not my problem. The problem is that php doesn't save session while script has not finished.